# sqlAlchemy does not recognise changes to DB made outside of session

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

Something peculiar I've noticed is that any changes committed to the DB **outside of the session** (such as ones made in MySQL's Workbench) are not recognised in the sqlAlchemy session. I have to close and open a new session for sqlAlchemy to recognise it.

For example, a row I deleted manually is still fetched from sqlAlchemy.

This is how I initialise the session:

```
engine   = create_engine('mysql://{}:{}@{}/{}'.format(username, password, host, schema), pool_recycle=3600)
Session  = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session  = Session()
metadata = MetaData()
```

How can I get sqlAlchemy to recognise them?

My sqlAlchemy version is 0.9.4 and my MySQL version is 5.5.34. We use only sqlAlchemy's Core (no ORM).

Comment: this may not be enough code to completely understand. do you call `session.add()` (or similar) and `session.commit()`?

Comment: I do in several places where I `update` or `insert` into the database. Otherwise no. I'm only interested to learn why a deleted row from the DB is still fetched by sqlAlchemy's session. In essence, do I need to periodically call `commit()` to ensure those changes are picked up or even every time before I query for a row?

Comment: Try this http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/dialects/mysql.html#mysql-isolation-level with "READ_COMMITTED".

Comment: @pavel_form That seems to have fixed it, thanks very much! Add it as an answer so I can upvote it and accept it if you like :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To be able to read committed data from others transactions you'll need to set transaction isolation level to `READ COMMITTED`. For sqlalchemy and mysql:

To set isolation level using `create_engine()`:

```py
engine = create_engine(
    "mysql://scott:tiger@localhost/test",
    isolation_level="READ COMMITTED")
```

To set using per-connection execution options:

```py
connection = engine.connect()
connection = connection.execution_options(
    isolation_level="READ COMMITTED")
```

[source](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html#transaction-isolation-level)